# Customize the display of a theorem

Tags: spacing

I have a theorem for which I do not have a proof. What I mean is that I have a paragraph under it, but I do not want it to start with the word `Proof`. Instead I want that only the first line of the paragraph to be indented.

This is what I have so far:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt,twoside]{report}
\usepackage{mystyle}
\setlength{\headheight}{42pt}
\setlength{\parskip}{0.3cm}
\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}

\newtheorem{theorem}[lemma]{Theorem}

\begin{document}

\begin{theorem}
This is a theorem.
\end{theorem}
"Here begins the explanation
which is continued here
and here."

\end{document}
```

I have seen that I could use `\indent` in front of it, but this does not apply in my case since I have `\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}` before the start of the document.

How can I indent only the first line?

Comment: `\hspace*{1cm}`. By the way, why did you kill the `parindent`?

Comment: \hspace*{15pt} Your paragraph. However mixing indented and non-indented paragraphs is rather not a good typographic convention.

Comment: `\parindent` is usually `20pt` in the basic document classes.

Comment: @Sigur: Because I know that when you write something in English the paragraphs are not indented

Comment: Either you indent all your paragraphs (theorems are an exception because they are labelled) or none. Indent them and don't set a nonzero `\parskip`, your readers will be grateful.

Comment: @Przemysław Scherwentke: I just wanted a way to show that the text belongs to the theorem, but it is not a proof

Comment: @Jessy09 I read lots of books and papers in English and I couldn't find significant examples of non indented paragraphs.

Comment: @Jessy09, this is not common in math texts, for example.

Comment: In traditional typography, it's `1em` most of the time. It's better to use a font dependent unit.

Comment: @Jessy09 THE FIRST paragraph of a chapter may not be indented, but in general indentation is a standard customary.

Comment: I use nonindented paragraphs and with a line between them, instead of indented ones and with no line. This is how I knew it should be done. I'm sorry if I was misinformed.

Comment: It's another style of layout, but 1 line is certainly too much. Moreover it suggests, inn my opinion, that paragraphs are more or less independent.

Comment: Why don't you create a new theorem structure in the proof style (you might call it *scholia*), but without a label? The vertical spacing would be that of a proof, it even could use an  end-of-proof symbol.

Comment: @Bernard: because I only wanted to indent 1 paragraph from 1 theorem. Since it is such a small exception, I didn't think I will need to create a new theorem structure.

Comment: Either all paragraphs are indented (with the possible exception of those immediately following a chapter/section title), or none. There's no reason for indenting just one. If the paragraph doesn't start with “Proof” readers will know it isn't the proof, won't they?